# How to set a binding in Code?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have the need to set a binding in code.

I can't seem to get it right tho.

This is what i have tried:

XAML:

```
<TextBox Name="txtText"></TextBox>
```

Code behind:

```
Binding myBinding = new Binding("SomeString");
myBinding.Source = ViewModel.SomeString;
myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(txtText, TextBox.TextProperty, myBinding);
```

ViewModel:

```
public string SomeString
    {
      get
      { 
          return someString;
      }
      set 
      { 
          someString= value;
          OnPropertyChanged("SomeString");
      }
    }
```

The property is not updating when i set it.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 220, accepted):

Replace:

```
myBinding.Source = ViewModel.SomeString;
```

with:

```
myBinding.Source = ViewModel;
```

Example:

```
Binding myBinding = new Binding();
myBinding.Source = ViewModel;
myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("SomeString");
myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(txtText, TextBox.TextProperty, myBinding);
```

Your source should be just `ViewModel`, the `.SomeString` part is evaluated from the `Path` (the `Path` can be set by the constructor or by the `Path` property).

Comment: You could also use txtText.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty,myBinding) in place of last line just to reduce typing :)

Comment: @ManishDubey The benefit of the static method is that the first parameter is defined as a DependencyObject, so it enables data binding on objects that don't derive from FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement (such as Freezables).

Comment: Thanks for this.  Struggled a bit looking for an example like this

Comment: Great! How do I clear that binding?

Answer (score 12):

You need to change source to viewmodel object:

```
myBinding.Source = viewModelObject;
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7525254/10927863) of [Dyppl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501518/dyppl), I think it would be nice to place this inside the `OnDataContextChanged` event:

```
private void OnDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Unforunately we cannot bind from the viewmodel to the code behind so easily, the dependency property is not available in XAML. (for some reason).
    // To work around this, we create the binding once we get the viewmodel through the datacontext.
    var newViewModel = e.NewValue as MyViewModel;

    var executablePathBinding = new Binding
    {
        Source = newViewModel,
        Path = new PropertyPath(nameof(newViewModel.ExecutablePath))
    };

    BindingOperations.SetBinding(LayoutRoot, ExecutablePathProperty, executablePathBinding);
}
```

We have also had cases were we just saved the `DataContext` to a local property and used that to access viewmodel properties. The choice is of course yours, I like this approach because it is more consistent with the rest. You can also add some validation, like null checks. If you actually change your `DataContext` around, I think it would be nice to also call:

```
BindingOperations.ClearBinding(myText, TextBlock.TextProperty);
```

to clear the binding of the old viewmodel (`e.oldValue` in the event handler).

Answer (score 0):

Example:

DataContext:

```
  class ViewModel
  {
    public string SomeString
    {
      get => someString;
      set 
      {
        someString = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SomeString));
      }
    }
  }
```

Create Binding:

```
  new Binding("SomeString")
  {
    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
  };
```