# Binding in code behind in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can I add a binding in code behind?

```
 <Canvas.Effect >
      <fx:GreenscreenEffect Tolerance="{Binding Value, ElementName=sliderGreenscreenTolerance}" 
                            ColorR="{Binding Value, ElementName=sliderGreenscreenR}"
                            ColorG="{Binding Value, ElementName=sliderGreenscreenG}"
                            ColorB="{Binding Value, ElementName=sliderGreenscreenB}" />
 </Canvas.Effect>
```

I tried without success:

```
GreenscreenEffect effect = new GreenscreenEffect() ;
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Tolerance");
binding.Source = sliderGreenscreenTolerance.Value; 
BindingOperations.SetBinding(effect, TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
// etc. for each property
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525185/how-to-set-a-binding-in-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GreenscreenEffect effect = new GreenscreenEffect() ;
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Value");
binding.Source = sliderGreenscreenTolerance; 
// effect.SetBinding(GreenscreenEffect.ToleranceProperty, binding);
// Commented above out since GreenscreenEffect is not a FrameworkElement, thus:
BindingOperations.SetBinding(effect, GreenscreenEffect.ToleranceProperty, binding);
// ... ColorRProperty etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
  GreenscreenEffect effect = new GreenscreenEffect() ;
                Binding binding = new Binding();
                binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Value");
                binding.Source = sliderGreenscreenTolerance; 
                BindingOperations.SetBinding(effect, GreenscreenEffect.ToleranceProperty, binding);
```

Comment: you found it as I was typing :) just letting know that you can use the `SetBinding` method on the control instead of the one in `BindingOperations`