# Binding list elements with label code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm try to bind struct list with labels that created dynamically.

code of structure:

```
public struct PrinterToGridBinds
        {
            public string extPrinterName { get; set; }
            public string extIcecreamType { get; set; }
            public string extBatchNumber { get; set; }
            public string extBeginingDate { get; set; }
            public string extPrinterState { get; set; }
            public string extBatchCounter { get; set; }
            public string extDIOCounter { get; set; }

            public PrinterToGridBinds(string extPrinterName, string extIcecreamType, string extBatchNumber, string extBeginingDate,
                string extPrinterState, string extBatchCounter, string extDIOCounter)
            {
                this.extPrinterName =  extPrinterName;
                this.extIcecreamType = extIcecreamType;
                this.extBatchNumber = extBatchNumber;
                this.extBeginingDate = extBeginingDate;
                this.extPrinterState = extPrinterState;
                this.extBatchCounter = extBatchCounter;
                this.extDIOCounter = extDIOCounter;
            }
        }

        public List<PrinterToGridBinds> lst_PrinterToGridBindings = new List<PrinterToGridBinds>();
```

Initialize list of structures

```
private void PrinterToGridBindingInit()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < PrinterNumber; i++)
            {
                lst_PrinterToGridBindings.Add(new PrinterToGridBinds("Num " + (i + 1).ToString(), "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"));
            }
        }
```

and try to bind this with labels that creating dynamically. Code below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                Label lbl_PrinterName = new Label();
                lbl_PrinterName.Name = "Name_" + i.ToString();
                Binding lbl_Binding = new Binding {Path = new PropertyPath(lst_PrinterToGridBindings[i].extPrinterName), Mode = BindingMode.OneWay };               
                lbl_PrinterName.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, lbl_Binding);

                Grid.SetRow(lbl_PrinterName, i + 2);
                Grid.SetColumn(lbl_PrinterName, 3);
                grd_WorkArea.Children.Add(lbl_PrinterName);
            }
```

And I don't see any result after program runs. From other side, if I define property

```
public string PropName1 { get; set; } = "PropTest";
```

and add this property to binding like this:

```
Binding lbl_Binding = new Binding {Path = new PropertyPath("PropName1"), Mode = BindingMode.OneWay };
```

All works like a charm! Where is my mistake?How to bind structure data with labels dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like, for your working sample (with `PropName`) you define the property name in property path, but for printers you define a property value `lst_PrinterToGridBindings[i].extPrinterName`. Have a look at [Binding.Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.path?view=netframework-4.7.2) property. You also should specify the `Source` for binding

Comment: thank you for the answer. I tried do it like name with quotes, but this is doesn't work because of variable "i".

Comment: @Alex You also should specify the `Source` for binding, according [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525185/how-to-set-a-binding-in-code)

Comment: Oh, yes! I'm forget about this absolutely. Changed my code to 

`Binding lbl_Binding = new Binding {Source = lst_PrinterToGridBindings[i],
                    Path = new PropertyPath("extPrinterName"),
                    Mode = BindingMode.OneWay };`

And this is works properly.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to show a list of elements, use an ItemsControl. Assign or bind its ItemsSource property to a collection of item objects. Set its ItemTemplate to a DataTemplate with UI elements that bind to properties of the item class.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="printerList">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding extPrinterName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Code behind:

```
printerList.ItemsSource = lst_PrinterToGridBindings;
```

For details, see [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).