# C# WPF Data grid display error: Object being displayed

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have assigned a list of reports to be displayed within a WPF datagrid.

All values which are properties of the report object are displaying fine, however the values for the objects contained within the reports constructor just displays a generic object name from the data grid and I'm unsure how to access any of the underlying properties from said objects to provide a more meaningful display to the user.

Report constructor:

```
 public Report(string reporterName, Asset asset, Location incidentLocation, Room room, string incidentType)
    {
        ReporterName = reporterName;
        Asset = asset;
        IncidentLocation = incidentLocation;
        Room = room;
        IncidentType = incidentType;
    }
```

Datagrid XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="ReportsGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="212" Margin="33,252,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="725"/>
```

Setting the datagrid with a list of report object:

```
List<Report> reports = new List<Report>();
reports.Add(report);

ReportsGrid.ItemsSource = reports;
```

[Current datagrid output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7r5F.png)

Any help or advice would be much appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you just give WPF an object it will call ToString() on it which, by default, gives the class name. You can show a property with dot notation in your xaml binding like `asset.someproperty` instead of just `asset`. If you want to display a representation of the entire object then override ToString() to return what you want.

Comment: Under what part of the xaml binding would I configure that property? I would like to take the underlying assetname property from the asset object to display.

Comment: Are the columns auto-generated or do you define DataGridColumn explicitly?

Comment: Auto-generated at the moment, happy to switch if it's a preferable implementation for what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the columns are automatically generated, they will display the result of the `ToString` method for an object, because there is no way of knowing how the display an instance of a custom type.

In case you can manually create your columns, you can specify a property path for already existing column types like `DataGridTextColumn`. Suppose that `Asset` has a string property called `Name`.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Reports}">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Asset" Binding="{Binding Asset.Name}"/>
      <!-- ...other columns -->
   </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

If your data type is more complex, you can instead use a `DataGridTemplateColumn` and create custom data templates for displaying and editing.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Asset">
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Report}">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Asset.Name}"/>
         <!-- ...other controls -->
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Report}">
         <TextBox Text="{Binding Asset.Name}"/>
         <!-- ...other controls -->
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

If you absolutely need to auto-generate your columns, you need to hook into the [`AutoGeneratingColumn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn?view=netcore-3.1) event in code-behind or in a custom behavior.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyDatagrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Reports}">
```

```
MyDatagrid.AutoGeneratingColumn += OnAutoGeneratingColumns;
```

Then change the automatically generated columns or even replace them. In the example below I replaced a column, but you could also just use the `e.Column` that is already generated, e.g. a `DataGridTextColumn` and [set the binding in its `Binding` property in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525185/how-to-set-a-binding-in-code) just like in the above example for manually generated columns.

```
private void OnAutoGeneratingColumns(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Column.Header.Equals("Asset"))
   {
      // Create a new template column
      var templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn
      {
         Header = e.PropertyName,
         // ...set other properties
      };

      // Create a data template (or get one from a resource dictionary)
      var template = new DataTemplate(typeof(Report));

      // ...populate the data template and set bindings if needed

      // Set the cell template
      templateColumn.CellTemplate = template;

      // Do the same as above for the editing template if needed
      templateColumn.CellEditingTemplate = template;

      // Overwrite the auto-generated column
      e.Column = templateColumn;
   }

   // ...handle other columns or leave them as they are
}
```