# How to Binding via C# code, not Binding via xaml?

Tags: c#, mvvm, binding

In xaml, `value = {binding viewmodelValue}` can be passed, but I don't know how to implement it in C#.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a binding in Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525185/how-to-set-a-binding-in-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the binding context to the ViewModel.
In your view backend you can set

```
public partial class MySampleBackendPage : ContentPage
{
    public MySampleBackendPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.BindingContext  = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

This would bind your context to the view model.

Say your ViewModel class looks like this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
  List<string> TextBoxValues = new List<string>();
}
```

Now You can bind it in xaml with the following:

```
<ListView x:Name="EmployeeView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding TextBoxValues}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Entry Text={Binding} BindingMode="TwoWay"/>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```